# how can I add the reference to a third party library when the web application is already in the webserver

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reference, webserver

I am working on a web application built with vb.net and asp.net. the web application is already stored in the web server. I am creating some new features in the web app.

If have to include new third party library (e.g; itextsharp etc) in the project how can I add reference to the dll files in the web server?

Will it work if I just copy the dll files in bin folder (in the web server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your dll file in bin folder and it should work properly.Adding third party dll is same as your own dll jsut add it in bin folder and reference it in your page where you will need it.